# VSCode Intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am typically used to period bringing up intellisense options.  When writing a C# file in VSCode, I see intellisense as I type, but disappear upon completion.  It does not provide any follow up suggestions, unlike Visual Studio.  Is this just me?  Did I break something?  I've tried uninstalling and re-installing, and removing all but the C# extension, but nothing seems to help.

Comment: VSCode is not as powerful as Visual Studio. VSCode is a lightweight open source **Editor**, and Visual Studio is a full **IDE**.

Comment: @hutusi I wasn't asking for a comparison.  I know VSCode.  I prefer it over VStudio.  I just can't make sense of why this fresh install of VSCode is not behaving like other installs.